# Why can't I associate a private EC2 IP with an Elastic IP from VPC

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I have three entries in my `/etc/network/interfaces` with

```
eth0:0...
eth0:1...
eth0:2...
```

and the ips

```
10.0.0.210
10.0.0.211
10.0.0.212
```

...they're all working fine.

So I added a new entry, `eth0:3`, with the address `10.0.0.213`. Now, when I go to my AWS console and click on Elastic IP from the VPC dashboard, and try to associate an Elastic IP, the new ip I just created doesn't show up.

I've restarted `/etc/init.d/networking` and `ifconfig` shows that everything is working properly.

Here's what I see when I try to associate an Elastic IP. I've refreshed it a bunch of times, waited hours, and even rebooted the server. `10.0.0.213` just won't show up.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Adding an IP to `/etc/network/interfaces` doesn't in any way mean Amazon routes data there. You configured a private IP without actually setting it up with the actual AWS network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

If anyone else if facing this, just follow these steps:

1. Go the ec2 dashboard.
2. From the left sidebar, click Network Interfaces
3. Right click on the instance in question from the list
4. Click **Manage Private IP Addresses**
5. Add the new *private* ip in the list

Then you'll be able to associate it. Enjoy!